# How to copy the entire outlook message content in python

Tags: python, email, outlook

I'm a beginner trying to achieve the below in my python script: Can anyone help me on this? I'm stuck at step2.

1. Input: A locally saved outlook mail (*.msg) path
2. Go to the path and Copy the entire body of the mail
3. Create a new mail and paste the contents into new mail
4. send it manually

...

```
    import win32com.client as win32  

    ########### Functions
    def getMailBody(msgFile):
        start_text = "<html>"
        end_text = "</html>"
        with open(msgFile) as f:
            data=f.read()
        return data[data.find(start_text):data.find(end_text)+len(end_text)]

    def releaseMail(body, subject, recipient):
        outlook = win32.Dispatch('outlook.application')
        mail = outlook.CreateItem(0)
        mail.To = recipient
        mail.Subject = subject
        mail.HtmlBody = body
        mail.Display(True)

    ############### Main ################
    msgFile = "C:\\RELM\\testMsg.msg"
    mailTo = "mymail@myserver.com"
    mailSubject = "Test message"
    mailBody = getMailBody(msgFile)
    releaseMail(mailBody, mailSubject, mailRecipient)
```

...`

## Below is the error I'm getting.

File "C:\Python\Python38-32\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 23, in decode
return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x81 in position 924: character maps to undefined

Comment: Updated getMailBody function as below and there is no issue now. However, as I check the new mail that gets created, the format is all gone. 

    outlook = win32.Dispatch('outlook.application').GetNamespace("MAPI")
    msg = outlook.OpenSharedItem(msgFile)
    return msg.Body

How can i retain the format of the original mail?

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work but I'm not currently able to test it:

```
outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")
def getMailBody(msgFile):
        msgText = outlook.OpenSharedItem(msgFile)
        return msgText.Body
```